# OpenId Connect, Query Microsoft Graph

Tags: javascript, azure, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

We have a .Net Web Application that uses Single Sign On implemented by OpenID Connect to create an ID token and log a user in. Specifically `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect` and `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect`

I now have a requirement to query Microsoft Graph API via JavaScript.

In order for me to query Graph API I assume I need an Access token (plus I want to be mindful of token expiry and refresh).

What is the recommended approach to get from Single Sign On producing an ID token on the backend to querying Microsoft Graph API via JavaScript on the front end? Ideally I wouldn't put an proxy/pass-through API inbetween to get an Auth Token on my behalf.

Comment: The reason no one has answered this is that it's far too broad. There are multiple documents on the MS docs about this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

The main application uses OpenID Connect to establish an ID Token. I then use MSAL.js to silently login utilizing my already established SSO session.

This is the sample I followed:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-browser-samples/VanillaJSTestApp2.0/app/ssoSilent

I then can acquire an access token to query Graph API.